# MySQL query not showing correct data

Tags: mysql, limit, between

Hay Everyone, i have a MySQL query

```
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `price` BETWEEN '60' AND '999' ORDER BY `product` DESC LIMIT 12 OFFSET 0
```

This obviously select 12 products where the price is between 60 and 999. This shows the rows correctly.

However if i increase the limit like this query

```
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `price` BETWEEN '60' AND '1000' ORDER BY `product` DESC LIMIT 12 OFFSET 0
```

No rows get shown. Any ideas why this happens? The 'price' field is float type field

Comment: Is the price column alphanumeric? If yes, that holds the key of failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the ' because the field types are numbers, not chars.

Comment: This corrects the issues, how come it was working when the number was below 999?

Answer (score 0):

You are treating `'60'` and `'1000'` as characters. Use numbers:

```
where `price` between 60 and 1000
```

If you use varchar strings, there is **no row** that will match a `between`'60' and '1000'`condition, since`'1000'`is smaller than`'60'` in varchars.

It was working with `'999'` because there are probably a couple of prices ranged between `'6'` and `'9'`.

```
mysql> select '60' < '9';
+------------+
| '60' < '9' |
+------------+
|          1 | 
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

The 60, 999 and 1000 are getting treated as chars instead of float or int,

The reason it works with 999 is because the comparision happens on ascii chars.

For 1000, you wont get any rows which will have price with ascii starting between 6 and 1 since 6 has higher value than 1.